# React child component not updating parents state, so second child is not noticing the changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Curently I have this structure.

```
Child1 <---- Parent ----> Child2
```

Parent component has this  state

```
    this.state = {
            authenticationChecked: true,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            sideBarRetracted: false
        }

this.retract = this.retract.bind(this);
        this.unretract = this.unretract.bind(this);
```

and the following functions

```
retract() {
    this.setState({
        sideBarRetracted: true
    }, () => {
        console.log("retracted")
        console.log(this.state.sideBarRetracted) //I can see this changing to true, but the child wont take it into effect, even tho if i hardcode it , it will
    });
}

unretract() {
    this.setState({
        sideBarRetracted: false
    })
    console.log("unretracted")
}
```

Which is pased to both childs

```
<SideBar retract={this.retract} unretract={this.unretract} retracted={this.state.sideBarRetracted} {...this.props}/> 
<PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/skadi" render={(props) => <Skadi retracted={this.state.sideBarRetracted} {...props}/>} />
```

Now my question is. I supposedly should receive that as a prop in a child component, for example lets say in the sidebar component which is a child. Whose constructor is this, and im supposed to receive the prop there and assign it to the state

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        retracted: this.props.retracted
    }

}
```

It works properly so far, but now I have the following issue. This same component has a function onClick() which will change that specific state

```
       <FontAwesomeIcon className="registerIcon" icon={faArrowAltCircleLeft} onClick={this.props.retract} />
<FontAwesomeIcon className="expandicon-retracted" icon={faArrowAltCircleRight} onClick={this.props.unretract} />
```

But point is, this is not working, the state is not being updated in the parent component. I can change it manually (hardcoding) and I see the child component reacting to the change, but i cant make it react with the onclick() update

At the same time, I have my Child2 component, who has been passed the parent state as well. Will its state update if I update the parent component using CHILD1 ?

I have seen that i should use something like this in the child2 , but well it wont work so far (mainly because parent component isnt updated afaik)

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        sideretracted: false
    }
    console.log("props in skadi")

}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ sideretracted: nextProps.sideBarRetracted});
  }
```

Comment: Child should never change parents state, refer to official document

Comment: @keikai how else would i connect child1 and child2 sharing a specific state? The workaround I see is setting that state in the parent of both childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set the child state from the props received from the parent component.
Since you are updating the state of child component from the methods bound to the child components it isn't reflected in the parent component.
One thing you could do is pass a method from the parent to update the state of the parent component and the child state gets updated by itself since it will be passed the new state variable from parent as a prop.
You could have the `toggleRetract` method defined in the parent to set the parent state and pass it as a prop to the child component which would trigger it and set the parent state for you which will be passed down to the children components as props (like how you are passing the state props).

For example

```js
function Toggle() {
  const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false)
  const toggle = () => setOn(o => !o)
  return <Switch on={on} onToggle={toggle} />
}
function Switch({on, onToggle}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>The button is {on ? 'on' : 'off'}</div>
      <button onClick={onToggle}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here Toggle is the parent component and Switch is the child component and the parent component passes the `on` state as well as `onToggle` method which the child component uses to display and update the state respectively.
More info [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling)

Comment: I have updated the code, I have moved the functions to the parent component, and now im triggering them by pasing those functions inside the child componends, and doing a this.props.retract onClick. Point is, i can see the state being updated with console.log , but child component doesnt seem to take that change into account, since it will only react if i hardcode the state in the parent component, but wont react if i use the function (even tho as i said i can see the state change with console.log)

Comment: fixed it using a componentDidUpdate()